# How to get a Logger that Prints to Console and to File in fewest lines

Tags: python, logging

This is how I obtain a logger that prints to both console and a file:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler2 = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0], 'my.log'), mode='w')
handler2.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.addHandler(handler2)
```

Is there a way to accomplish something similar to this in fewer operations? I don't particularly care about the mode of the file or the filename.

Edit: The use case for this is when I'm prototyping a new script and do not wish to spend the time writing a configuration file until later.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion: when you are prototyping, you want a log file for each module.

### A contextual handler

To do that, you can process as follow:

- Create a `LogNameFileHandler`: this is a subclass of `logging.StreamHandler` which behave like `logging.FileHandler`, but which create a log file for each logger (based on their name).
- Create a singleton `LOGGER` which set up a (the) root logger with this handler and the classic console logger (the way you suggest).
- Use you logger in different module the simplest way: `logger = LOGGER.getChild(__name__)`.

### Details implementation

In `log_handler.py`:

```
import io
import logging
import os


class LogNameFileHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, mode='a', encoding=None):
        super(LogNameFileHandler, self).__init__(stream=None)
        self.root_dir = os.path.abspath(root_dir)
        self.mode = mode
        self.encoding = encoding
        # Set stream to None, because StreamHandler set it to sys.stderr
        self.stream = None
        #: :type log_path: str
        self.log_path = None

    def _open(self):
        log_dir = os.path.dirname(self.log_path)
        if not os.path.isdir(log_dir):
            os.makedirs(log_dir)
        return io.open(self.log_path, mode=self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)

    def close(self):
        self.acquire()
        try:
            try:
                if self.stream:
                    try:
                        self.flush()
                    finally:
                        stream = self.stream
                        self.stream = None
                        if hasattr(stream, "close"):
                            stream.close()
            finally:
                super(LogNameFileHandler, self).close()
        finally:
            self.release()

    def emit(self, record):
        name = record.name.replace(".", os.sep)
        log_name = name + ".log"
        self.log_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, log_name)
        self.stream = self._open()
        super(LogNameFileHandler, self).emit(record)
```

This handler opens a new file for each `emit`, of course, it's up to you to handle a cache… For prototyping, it should be OK. You can use a mapping `record.name` => `stream`.

In `log_setup.py`:

```
import logging
import os

from log_handler import LogNameFileHandler


def _init_logger(log_dir, name=None):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(u'%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    handler1 = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler1.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler2 = LogNameFileHandler(log_dir, mode="a+", encoding="utf8")
    handler2.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler1)
    logger.addHandler(handler2)
    return logger


LOGGER = _init_logger(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This module defines the `LOGGER` singleton, which you canuse in all yours Python modules…

### Usage

In your `package/module.py`:

```
from log_setup import LOGGER

logger = LOGGER.getChild(__name__)
logger.info("hello solution3")
```

That’s all (all the dust is under the rug).

If you set up the `root` logger, you can aslo write:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious: why do you want that?

You can use an external configuration in an INI file and load it with `logging.config.fileConfig`.

Or

Create your own handle which combine file and console handlers.

Or

Create a file-like object which writes it a file and in the console. Then use this file with `logging.basicConfig`.

Comment: The use case is for when I am quickly prototyping a new script, and don't want to write a configuration file until later. I'll update my question